# Setting up Spring JTA transaction in Jboss 7.1.1

Tags: spring, jboss, spring-data-jpa, jta

Hello I am trying to setup spring JTA in myEclipse for Spring.Below are my configuration files:

applicationContent.xml where i have added two imports(note it do include schema locations)

```
<import resource="infrastructure.xml"/>
<import resource="classpath:**/persistence.xml"/>
```

infrastrutre.xml(unable to add schema due to input validations)

```
<bean
    class="org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor" />

    <bean id="emf" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="jtaDataSource" ref="masterDataSource" />
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter" ref="jpaVendorAdapter" />
    </bean>

    <!-- <bean id="masterDataSource" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
    <property name="jndiName" value="java:/test_JTA"></property>
</bean> -->

<jee:jndi-lookup id="masterDataSource" jndi-name="java:/Test_JTA" />

<bean id="jpaVendorAdapter"
    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
<!--     <property name="databasePlatform" 
        value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect" /> -->
    <property name="database" value="MYSQL" />
    <property name="showSql" value="true" />
    <property name="generateDdl" value="true" />
</bean>

<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.transaction.jta.JtaTransactionManager" />
    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>

    <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor" />
```

persistence.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="1.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence">
  <persistence-unit name="mainPU" transaction-type="JTA">
    <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
   <class>com.abc.PaymentCard</class>
    <jar-file>mysql-connector-java-5.1.23-bin.jar</jar-file>
    <properties>
      <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect"/>
      <property name="hibernate.transaction.jta.platform" value="org.hibernate.service.jta.platform.internal.JBossAppServerJtaPlatform"/>
        <property key="hibernate.transaction.factory_class">org.hibernate.transaction.CMTTransactionFactory</property>
  <property key="hibernate.transaction.manager_lookup_class">org.hibernate.transaction.JBossTransactionManagerLookup</property>
    </properties>
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

I am getting error
JBAS010402: Unable to instantiate driver class "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver": org.jboss.msc.service.DuplicateServiceException: Service jboss.jdbc-driver.JTA_Test_war is already registered

I goggled this error but still haven't got any satisfactory answers.Kindly help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i know its late but, i believe i fixed this error by using a different factory class.

```
<property name="hibernate.transaction.factory_class" value="org.hibernate.ejb.transaction.JoinableCMTTransactionFactory"/>
```

hope it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about JBoss but for Glassfish there is an Ext directory for the Jars you want in the Classpath. So try to figure out how to deploy mysql-connector-java*.jar to your domain.

Comment: thanks for reply,issue was fixed after some tweaks here and there.